# Fullscreen from javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I have a swf file and i want to able to fullscreen this swf file using javascript. I have a button to access function inside of swf but it gives me error. I searched over google but nothing good i found. Is it impossible or i do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Fullscreen in Adobe Flash can only be triggered within a `click` event handler inside ActionScript. Flash won't allow fullscreen in any other way because of security concerns (think screen hijacking).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000352.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.

And from a users point of view it **should** not be possible. No program accessible by just opening a website should be allowed to overtake my desktop and switch into fullscreen without my explicit consent to do so.